# Playing video from server is not working in MediaPlayer Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, xcode5

Here i want to play videos from server using MediaPlayer framework. 1)I am adding mediaplayer framework. 2)I am importing #import header file 3)I implemented code by using google.

My Code is :

```
- (void)act_GoToVideoPlayer:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSString* resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[postMediaFileArr objectAtIndex:sender.tag]]; //Video file URL is getting from server and stored it in a MutableArray
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: resourcePath];
    mediaplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    [mediaplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 250, 150)];
    [self.view addSubview:mediaplayer.view];

    mediaplayer.fullscreen = YES;
    mediaplayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    mediaplayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    mediaplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
}
```

The view goes to blank screen and infinite loading when this function is called. I have tried many other versions of this implementation and the results are all fail. The log in the is particular case is:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

If i passed any other videos from websites. it will be playing audios not videos. 
Got ideas on the cause? This is my first venture into playing video and it has turned out to be a nightmare at this point.

Comment: add this line in your code mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
.

Comment: Hi @Rushabh - Thanks for your immediate response. i added this line also. But same warning is coming and audio & video both are not working.

Comment: can you know me the extesntion of that video ?

Comment: http://54.84.51.5/video/afa46dd05f9b8116e74f245379e8428avideo.mov this is my video file url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)notifyCompletelyVisible
{
    
        NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"*YOUR URL*"];
        _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:aUrl];
        _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        _moviePlayer.view.frame = asyvideoImage.frame;
        _moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
        [self.view addsubview _moviePlayer.view];
        [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
        
}
```

this is working just import

## import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"

Comment: How you set contentView.

Comment: sorry you have to just add _movieplayer to your view

Comment: i add like this [self.view addSubview:mediaplayer.view];

Comment: _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}

Comment: add to you code static URL : and check  https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/9D3D08CEE31035360386272358400_1e03d0e58d8.4.7.16276969947760525878_WYgAp7hEFCoYQQWtZE9XYfUUyTjQek4o0WgalwhQyHZ5zZSLWKFr.GE4uAZiDAqE.mp4?versionId=fxgkYqC3tVFLoGiwFxMtKnkbDd7EpNoY

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48272/discussion-between-sabs-and-mits-bhadeshiya)

Answer (score 0):

you try in .h:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

and you add delegate

```
interface YourViewcontroler : UIViewController <MPMediaPlayback>
{
 MPMoviePlayerController *player;
}
```

and in your .m file:

```
-(void) launchVideo{
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString* myURL =@"http://yourUrl/file.mp4";
    NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
    player  = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];
    [player view].alpha=1;
    [appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:[player view]];
    [player play];
}
```

and the delegate methode for finishing:

```
-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player stop];
    player=nil;
    [player release];
}
```

i hope this help you